# UIImageView does not display

Tags: xcode, layout, uiimageview, constraints

Created the same type of UIView in an iOS 8 project: 3 letter country code (ex. USA, SUI, ESP, GER) UILabel with the representative .png image for the flag of the country beside it:
SUI IMAGE HERE
Dropped a UILabel; defined the Outlet; ditto the UIIMageView. Used the same constraints: UILabel is centered horizontally and 20 below the previous label (going down the display); then for the flag I create Height and Width constraints (33x48), a constraint to to center it vertically with the center of the label; a constraint to offset the leading edge 20 to the right of the label. 
It does not display.
There is a 'trailing constraint missing which may cause overlapping with other views' warning msg when I compile. 
I've tried the suggestions in other SO items - use '<=' or '>=' instead of equal; use only height then set an aspect ratio. I even tried resolve auto layout issues' which added a trailing constraint.  Nothing worked. 
This image is how it appears in the iOS 8 project:
[image]

Comment: Current Xcode version: 9.0.1

Comment: Resolved issue: had to move all .png files out of 'Supporting Files' (or other name) sub-directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move .png files to main directory. Xcode no longer will look in subdirectories (i.e. 'Supporting Files', 'Resources','Images', etc).